# making scalloped potatoes, need to be in oven for 3 hours,what temperature should I have them on

Tags: baking

I need to put scalloped potatoes in the oven for 3 hours, what tempterature should I have them on?

Comment: What is the need to have them in the oven so long?

Comment: I think until you explain your reasoning for this time period you are unlikely to get good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I found a recipe for slow baked potatoes that has the potatoes in the oven for 3 hours set at 350F. According to the author:

"The accepted practice is to bake potatoes for an hour. But here's how long to bake a baked potato if you want it to be nutty and soft: three hours, yes, that's no typo, it really is 'three' hours. The skin and flesh are both completely delicious when slow-baked for a long time."

Recipe [here](http://kitchen-parade-veggieventure.blogspot.com/2007/09/sloooow-baked-potatoes.html).

However, I am unsure whether this theory holds true for scalloped potatoes. Most scalloped potatoes recipes I came across had the potatoes being baked in the oven for ~1 hr at ~350F.

Comment: I want to try that 3 hour baker.  But as far as the question, I would think three hours at anything above 250 or so would be dangerous.  Scalloped potatoes usually include dairy (milk and/or cheese), and I think the proteins in there wouldn't like a long, slow cook like that.  It may take a few tries, but I would imagine baking around 300 covered for 2-2.5 hours would be ok, then uncover, add cheese on top, and up the temp to 400 to get the bubbly crust.

Comment: @JSM I can understand worrying about overcooking, but *dangerous*?

Comment: @Jefromi Not dangerous like base-jumping while drunk.  Danger isn't always life threatening...  That being said, I am not sure at what temperature potatoes and/or dairy carbonizes or ignites.  Probably 450 or more.  Still not jumping-dangerous, but possibly burn-out-your-oven dangerous.

Comment: @JSM I knew you probably didn't mean it'd blow up your house, but you just said "dangerous", no way for anyone to have any idea what kind of danger you meant. And I definitely disagree: you're not going to set anything on fire. Even without the liquid, you'd at worst char things, but it'd just ruin your food (and maybe your pan). With scalloped potatoes, worst case is burning/browning it onto the pan, and charring the top. (But at 350F I'm not sure you'd even char the top in 3 hours...)

Answer (score 1):

Baking mine at 265F for 2.5 hrs. Same as my spiral cut Ham. Turned out beautiful. No char, no burning. Milk proteins stayed intact and became the creamy addition they were meant to be. I used half and half.

Answer (score -2):

350° for amt. time, check slice. Also use greased, Pam fine, whatever vessel using!!!